# Possible to implement own linux app with Apple AirPlay?

Tags: linux, streaming, airplay

Hi I am trying to build an embedded ARM board with toslink for my hifi amplifier. and the ARM is built with 720Mhz and running ARM version of ubuntu 12.04 linux.

Is there any open source module/library to implement Apple Airplay? So I can stream my music to my high quality audio to my board and finally to drive my speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.flyn.org/projects/libdmapsharing/

> Libdmapsharing also detects audio AirPlay services; coupled with the
>   AirPlay™ support in PulseAudio or GStreamer, this can allow an
>   application to stream audio to an AirPlay device.

Comment: let me give ya feedback after i try it

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a node.js module with AirPlay support, which you can find on NPM or on github:

https://github.com/lperrin/node_airtunes

I included an example to stream an MP3 file to a nearby server.

```
node play_ffmpeg.js --host <Your AirPlay Host> --port <Your AirPlay Port> --file <Your MP3 file> --ffmpeg <Path to FFmpeg>
```